# Handle more than on input file on a form jquery asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form, on which the user must input some values, and attach a file. Then there is a button that adds those data to an HTML table. The submit button, takes all data in the array and must upload also all files.
So my question is, is there a way to get all files and upload them using C# in ASP.Net MVC.

Here is some code of the form and the table:

```
<div class='wizard-tab' stepname='step3'>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <h6><strong><i class="fas fa-house-user"></i></strong> Structure Details</h6>
                    <span class="small">#3</span>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group row alert alert-danger" style="display:none" id="tableStructureError"></div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>GPS</label>
                        <input type="text" id="structureGPS" class="form-control" placeholder="GPS" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Structure</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="structureCode" data-placeholder="Structure Code"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Roof</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="toitCode" data-placeholder="Toiture"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Wall</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="murCode" data-placeholder="Mur"></select>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Sol</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="solCode" data-placeholder="Sol Code"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Usage</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="structureUsage"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-row">
                        Surface/Pieces
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" id="structureSurface" placeholder="Size(mxm)" />
                        <input type="number" class="form-control col-md-4" id="structurePiece" placeholder="pieces" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Owner</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="structureOwner" data-placeholder="Owner Type"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label>Photo ID</label>
                        <input type="text" id="structurePictureID" class="form-control" placeholder="Photo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <label>Structure Photo</label>
                        <input id="structurePhoto" name="structurePhoto" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false" data-theme="fas" data-show-upload="false" data-show-cancel="false" data-allowed-file-extensions='["jpg","jpeg","png"]' data-el-Error-Container="#structurePhoto-errors">
                        <div id="structurePhoto-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-rounded-f" role="button" type="button" id="addStructure">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="structureTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> GPS</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> STR</th> 
                                <th> STR</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Roof ID</th> 
                                <th> Roof</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Photo</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Wall</th> 
                                <th> Wall</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Soil</th> 
                                <th> Soil</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Usage</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Usage</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Area</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Piece</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Photo Link</th> 
                                <th style="display:none"> Owner</th> 
                                <th> Owner</th> 
                                <th> </th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="structureTableBody">
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My jQuery code is like this:

```
//Code that adds data form input files to html array is(Note that everything is working fine):
$('#addStructure').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var errors = [];

    if ($("#structureCode").val() == "" || $("#structureCode").val() == null || isNaN($("#structureCode").val()))
        errors.push("Structure Code can not be empty");
    if ($("#toitCode").val() == "" || $("#toitCode").val() == null || isNaN($("#toitCode").val()))
        errors.push("Roof Code can not be empty");
    if ($("#murCode").val() == "" || $("#murCode").val() == null || isNaN($("#murCode").val()))
        errors.push("Wall Code can not be empty");
    if ($("#solCode").val() == "" || $("#solCode").val() == null || isNaN($("#solCode").val()))
        errors.push("Floor Code can not be empty");
    if ($("#structureOwner").val() == "" || $("#structureOwner").val() == null || isNaN($("#structureOwner").val()) || $("#structureOwner").val() < 1)
        errors.push("Please specify Ownership of this structure");
    if ($("#structurePictureID").val() == "" || $("#structurePictureID").val() == null)
        errors.push("Please specify picture ID of this structure");
    if ($("#structurePhoto").val() == "" || $("#structurePhoto").val() == null)
        errors.push("Please upload the picture of this structure");
    if ($("#structureUsage").val() == "" || $("#structureUsage").val() == null || isNaN($("#structureUsage").val()))
        errors.push("Choose the structure Usage");
    if ($("#structureSurface").val() == "" || $("#structureSurface").val() == null)
        errors.push("Structure surface can't be empty");
    if ($("#structurePiece").val() == "" || $("#structurePiece").val() == null || isNaN($("#structurePiece").val()))
        errors.push("Specify the number of rooms");
    if ($("#structureGPS").val() == "" || $("#structureGPS").val() == null)
        errors.push("You didn't add the structure GPS ID");
    if (notInTables($("#structureGPS").val()) == true)
        errors.push("This GPS ID is already used");
    if (notInTables($('#structurePictureID').val()) == true)
        errors.push("This picture ID is already used");

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        var errorMessage = "<ul>";
        $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
            errorMessage += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
        });
        errorMessage += "</ul>";
        $("#tableStructureError").html(errorMessage).show(250);
    }
    else {
        var tr = "";
        tr += '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + $('#structureGPS').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structureCode').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#structureCode option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#toitCode').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#toitCode option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structurePictureID').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#murCode').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#murCode option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#solCode').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#solCode option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structureUsage').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structureUsage option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structureSurface').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structurePiece').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structurePhoto').val() + '</td>' +
            '<td style="display:none">' + $('#structureOwner').val() +'</td>' +
            '<td>' + $('#structureOwner option:selected').text() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="removeStructure" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="Remove Structure"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt danger"></i></a> ' + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';

        $("#structureTable tbody").append(tr);
        $('#structurePiece, #structureSurface, #structurePictureID, #structureGPS').val('');
        $("#structureCode, #toitCode, #murCode, #solCode, #structureOwner, #structureUsage").val("-1");
        $('#structurePhoto').fileinput('clear');
        $('#structureGPS').focus();
    }
    return false;
});

//function that convert html table to an array
function convertTableToArray(tableName) {
    var dataArray = [];
    $("#"+tableName ).find('tr').each(function (rowIndex, r) {
        var cols = [];
        $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex, c) {
            cols.push(c.textContent.trim());
        });

        if (cols.length > 0) {
            dataArray.push(cols);
        }
    });
    return dataArray;
}

//calling the function in document ready to display the table content
var structureArray = convertTableToArray("structureTable");
console.log(structureArray);
```

How can I handle all files that will be uploaded in my Controller? If it is just one file, I can use the form data API for HTML5 to get the file on the controller. Or what can be the easiest way to handle it.

Thanks,

Comment: please share the code how you intend to send the data from the client to your controller.   jquery ajax? or simple form submit (post)?

Comment: I want to use jquery ajax @charly1212

Comment: I find a solution: just add all input files to formdata object. I also create an object that contains all input text. Then in my ajax code, I pass the form data. In my controller, i get all files and my object.